# Custom view with text floating in background (like Voice Control app)

Tags: ios, animation, text, background, custom-controls

How would I go about creating a view where the background has various text strings floating by at different opacities and speeds, like in the Voice Control app's background? I'd appreciate any code or places where to look. Thanks!

BTW I'd prefer a solution that isn't 4.0 specific...I have to run this on a first-gen device, so 3.1.3's API is as high as I can use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UILabels` programmatically, with variations on opacity, color, and font, then animate them across the view. Just changing the location of the labels in a loop will result in the location being animated around.

You could also do it in Core Text, but it wouldn't gain you anything and would be **significantly** more difficult to animate.